# Is there a way to test the existence of a parameter in the parameter map?

Tags: mybatis

Is there a way in mybatis to test if a certain parameter is contained in the query parameter map?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
<select id="selectByKey" resultMap="MyObjectMap" parameterType="map">
    select obj.* from obj where obj.id=#{id:VARCHAR}
<!-- I'm looking for a method like that below -->
    <if test="parameterExists('forUpdate')">
        <if test="forUpdate == 1">
            for update
        </if>
    </if>
</select>
```

Comment: under `forUpdate` do you mean a key in the map?

Comment: not sure that #{id:VARCHAR} is a correct syntax. I've used to use that as #{id, jdbcType=VARCHAR}.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this test:

```
<if test="_parameter.containsKey('forUpdate')">your code....</if>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<if test="forUpdate != null">
```

may work.

In java HashMap.get(key) return null when key doesn't exist in map.